# SuSE - How to restart linux background process, that was started by user with keyboard inputs, after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, suse

I have a bash script that takes user inputs (name, password) and starts another bash script by passing these inputs.

Problem: This background process is stopping on system reboot

Question: How can I make this process survive reboots (restart on boot)?

mytool.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "username:" username
read -sp "password:" password
echo ""

exec 3<<<"$username/$password"
./mytoolsvc.sh > console.out &
```

mytoolsvc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
params=($(cat 0<&3))
...
```

mytoolsvc is dying on system reboot. I would like this process to start automatically after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This is false security. The password is still visible to anyone (`pgrep -fl mytoolsvc.sh`). You might as well store it in a config file somewhere. Then you can make it a service that will start after reboot.

Comment: actually i am doing this to hide them from ps "exec 3<<<username,password" and reading from "params=($(cat 0<&3))"